# PayPal Express Checkout Payment method disappear from front end after Upgrade to Magento 2.1.8?

Tags: php, magento2

I upgraded Magento 2.1.7 to Magento 2.1.8. All is working fine expect PayPal Express.

From backend, it's enabled but in the front-end, it's not visible on the checkout page. Another payment method like Sage pay is showing on the checkout page.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have tried many different options, but as of yet - no luck. I can get the logos to show on product, cart, and category page, but on step 2 of the checkout, there is no paypal option.

Comment: I have fixed it enabling "Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution". It's working with it but individually still not showing.

Comment: I almost get working using Payments Pro, but shows Credit Card options and PayPal Express, but both fail when try to use.

Comment: having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue with Magento 2.1.8. There are already a lot of Github issues on the magento Github repository (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10499)

As a workaround you could use Paypal via another provider like Adyen.